# LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl func1(struct Stru1 *)"

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, linker, unresolved-external

Let me edit the question:
The files are:

```
file1.h
file1.c
file3.h
file2.h
file2.c
file4.h
file5.h
main_code.cpp
```

file1.h

```
#include "file3.h"
typedef struct{} Str1;
void func1(Str1 *str1);
void func2(Str1 *str1);
```

file1.c

```
#include "file3.h"
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
void func1(Str1 *str1){}
void func2(Str1 *str1){}
```

file2.h

```
#include "file3.h"
#include "file1.h"
```

file2.c

```
#include "file3.h"
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

file3.h

```
Doesnt include others.
```

file4.h

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file5.h"
```

file5.h

```
#include "file3.h"
```

main_code.cpp

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"
#include "file4.h"
#include "file5.h"
func1(variable)
func2(variable)
```

The erro "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol" happen with func1 and func2 so I didnt place what functions the others have. I already tried placing the include in the "extern C" but didnt work.
And if I add to main_code.cpp

```
  #include "file1.c"
```

Then the program works...

Comment: You need to link all the compiled files together.

Comment: The linker says that missing function has a `struct Stru1` parameter, while file.h defines functions with `struct Str1` parameter. So maybe something is missing (or miscopied) either in your code or in the question.
Also, unless the compiler default language is C++, you need the extern "C" bracing C-implemented functions.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably forgot to add your file1.c to project for building.

Below is something you should not do in c++:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"  
    func1(variable);
    func2(variable);
 #include "file1.c"
#include "file2.c"
```

those #include "file1.c"/#include "file2.c", is whats your project is for - you add new files inside IDE.